# Can I publish a .Net application which is not ASP.NET 5 or ASP.NET Core in Docker containers?

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, boot2docker, docker-machine

Can we publish a .Net application which is not ASP.NET 5 or ASP.NET Core in Docker Containers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can publish other .NET applications based on either the full .NET framework (build your container images on the  https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet-framework/ base image) or the .NET Core framework (build your images on the https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/ as a base).

Remember that docker hosts services, so you wouldn't publish a Windows client like this, but background processes which typically run on a server.

So in theory you could convert your Windows services built on the full .NET Framework to be processes running in Docker containers.  They would not run as Windows services, but rather they would be stopped, started and managed using Docker.  If you are accessing other services - message queues, WCF etc, you may need to open ports into/out of your containers for them to talk to each other.

Depending on your situation, there may be benefits to doing this, but you should look carefully at whether it's the right direction for you.